# How can I return a list string from a Future

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder

I have a future call that I want to get 2 list Strings

But I get the return value it's a Future<List< dynamic >>

```
var datasource = const FutureInformation();

    getSliderDetailsEvents() async {
      SliderDetails futureEvents = await datasource.getSliderDetails();
      List<String> images = futureEvents.image; //List<String>
      List<String> titles = futureEvents.title; // List<String>

      List information = [images,titles]; //return an array
      return  information;
    }
```

How can I access the two List in this async call? I know as it's async I have to return a future, Would I have to create a FutureBuilder to create the List's.

Thanks

Comment: You can use the result inside the getSliderDetailsEvents but you can't return the sync value from the async context. Yes, you need to use a FutureBuilder if you need to use those values inside a Widget.

Comment: Thanks, I can use the Future Builder to create the List<String>?

Answer (score 0):

I answer here to format response better, you can do something like this from your code:

```
Future<List<String>> getSliderDetailsEvents() async {
      SliderDetails futureEvents = await datasource.getSliderDetails();
      List<String> images = futureEvents.image; //List<String>
      List<String> titles = futureEvents.title; // List<String>

      List<String> information = [...images,...titles]; //
      return  information;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the `Spread Operator ...`

```
Future<List<String>> getSliderDetailsEvents() async{
   SliderDetails futureEvents = await datasource.getSliderDetails();
      final images = futureEvents.image;
      final titles = futureEvents.title;
      return [...images, ...titles];
}
```

or you can do this like this

```
Future<List<String>> getSliderDetailsEvents() async{
  SliderDetails futureEvents = await datasource.getSliderDetails();
  return [...futureEvents.image, ...futureEvents.title];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to specify the type of objects that your list is storing (I assume you're creating a list of lists in your code):

```
  List<List<String>> information = <List<String>>[images,titles]; //return an array
```